# Error when implement an nodemcu 8266 with DHT22

Tags: macos, arduino-ide, nodemcu

I implemented a nodemcu 8266 as a api rest server with a temperature sensor (DHT22) in a Mac with macOS Monterey, when I read the temperature and humidity in a simple loop I don't have any problem, the implementation looks like this

```
#include <DHT.h>
#include <DHT_U.h>
float hum, temp;

DHT dht(D1, DHT22);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    dht.begin();
}

void loop() {
    temp = dht.readTemperature();
    hum = dht.readHumidity();
    Serial.println("Temperatura: " + String(temp) + " humedad: " + String(hum));
}
```

but when I implement a server api and try to read temperature to return that information the IDE return an error impossible to read

like this

```
User exception (panic/abort/assert)
--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------

Panic core_esp8266_main.cpp:137 __yield

>>>stack>>>

ctx: sys
sp: 3fffeab0 end: 3fffffb0 offset: 0000
3fffeab0:  5c93ba25 b85ced93 00000000 40102074  
3fffeac0:  000000fe 00000000 00000000 00000000  
3fffead0:  00000000 00000000 00000000 3ffeee38  
3fffeae0:  00000000 3ffe8a04 4bc6a7f0 3ffeec2c  
...
...
3fffffa0:  feefeffe feefeffe feefeffe 40207f46  
<<<stack<<<

--------------- CUT HERE FOR EXCEPTION DECODER ---------------

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,7)

load 0x4010f000, len 3460, room 16 
tail 4
chksum 0xcc
load 0x3fff20b8, len 40, room 4 
tail 4
chksum 0xc9
csum 0xc9
v0004a0b0
~ld
```

My code is

```
#include <DHT.h>
#include <DHT_U.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
#include <FS.h>

const char* ssid = "xxxxxxx";
const char* password = "xxxxxxx";
float hum, temp;

DHT dht(D1, DHT22);

void getSensorInformation(AsyncWebServerRequest *request)
{
  Serial.println("2...");
  temp = dht.readTemperature();
  Serial.println("1...");
  hum = dht.readHumidity();
  String message = "Temperatura: " + String(temp) + " humedad: " + String(hum);
  Serial.println(message);
  request->send(200, "text/plain", message);
}

void getIpAddress(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
  String ip = WiFi.localIP().toString();
  
  String message = "ip: " + ip;
  Serial.println(message);
  request->send(200, "text/plain", message);
}

AsyncWebServer server(80);

void notFound(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) {
   request->send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}

void InitServer()
{
   server.on("/ip", HTTP_GET, getIpAddress);
   server.on("/info", HTTP_GET, getSensorInformation);
   
   server.onNotFound(notFound);

   server.begin();
   Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void ConnectWiFi_STA() {
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("Connecting...");
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.print("Connected to WiFi network with IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  ConnectWiFi_STA();

  dht.begin();

  InitServer();
}

void loop() {
}
```

I create two methods, first `getIpAddress` that returns the IP of my computer and another that returns the sensor data, first method it works, but the second print until `2...`, so I think it failure in this line `temp = dht.readTemperature();` but I don't know why

PS: Sorry about my english my main language is spanish.

Comment: use the stack trace decoder

Comment: try `Serial.print("Temperatura: "); Serial.print(temp); Serial.print(" humedad: "); Serial.println(hum));`